# How to enqueue a task in a dynamic queue

Tags: c#, multithreading

I need to create a queue for different tasks. Currently this is done with a customized version of the example provided by http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Wait_and_Pulse:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class PCQueue
{
  readonly object _locker = new object();
  Thread[] _workers;
  Queue<Action> _itemQ = new Queue<Action>();

  public PCQueue (int workerCount)
  {
    _workers = new Thread [workerCount];

    // Create and start a separate thread for each worker
    for (int i = 0; i < workerCount; i++)
      (_workers [i] = new Thread (Consume)).Start();
  }

  public void Shutdown (bool waitForWorkers)
  {
    // Enqueue one null item per worker to make each exit.
    foreach (Thread worker in _workers)
      EnqueueItem (null);

    // Wait for workers to finish
    if (waitForWorkers)
      foreach (Thread worker in _workers)
        worker.Join();
  }

  public void EnqueueItem (Action item)
  {
    lock (_locker)
    {
      _itemQ.Enqueue (item);           // We must pulse because we're
      Monitor.Pulse (_locker);         // changing a blocking condition.
    }
  }

  void Consume()
  {
    while (true)                        // Keep consuming until
    {                                   // told otherwise.
      Action item;
      lock (_locker)
      {
        while (_itemQ.Count == 0) Monitor.Wait (_locker);
        item = _itemQ.Dequeue();
      }
      if (item == null) return;         // This signals our exit.
      item();                           // Execute item.
    }
  }
}
```

With the main method:

```
static void Main()
{
  PCQueue q = new PCQueue (2);

  Console.WriteLine ("Enqueuing 10 items...");

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    int itemNumber = i;      // To avoid the captured variable trap
    q.EnqueueItem (() =>
    {
      Thread.Sleep (1000);          // Simulate time-consuming work
      Console.Write (" Task" + itemNumber);
    });
  }

  q.Shutdown (true);
  Console.WriteLine();
  Console.WriteLine ("Workers complete!");
}
```

However while browsing the stackoverflow I stumbled over this modified version:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace Project
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Description of Multithread.
    /// </summary>
     public class Multithread<T> : IDisposable where T : class
    {
        object locker = new object();
        Thread[] workers;
        Queue<T> taskQ = new Queue<T>();

        public void TaskQueue(int workerCount)
        {
            workers = new Thread[workerCount];

            // Create and start a separate thread for each worker
            for (int i = 0; i < workerCount; i++)
                (workers[i] = new Thread(Consume)).Start();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            // Enqueue one null task per worker to make each exit.
            foreach (Thread worker in workers) EnqueueTask(null);
            foreach (Thread worker in workers) worker.Join();
        }

        public void EnqueueTask(T task)
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                taskQ.Enqueue(task);
                Monitor.PulseAll(locker);
            }
        }

        void Consume()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                T task;
                lock (locker)
                {
                    while (taskQ.Count == 0) Monitor.Wait(locker);
                    task = taskQ.Dequeue();
                }
                if (task == null) return;         // This signals our exit
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(task);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);              // Simulate time-consuming task
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which seems to provide a better usability. However I can't find out how to properly add a task to this queue.

```
classname testclass = new classname();
Multithread<classname> testthread = new Multithread<classname>();
```

I thought it would be something along the lines:

```
testthread.EnqueueTask(testclass.functioname());
```

However it doesn't seem to work. I'm stuck on this problem and couldn't find any help to this problem elsewhere.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Are taglines & signatures disallowed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed)" and "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see how `Multithread` provides better usability as it appears to a demonstration on how to implement the producer/consumer pattern in a generic way by not really deciding how to actually consume items. On the other hand `PCQueue` works with actions allowing it to actually consume items.

To modify `Multithread` to allow it do some work you can remove the generic type parameter `T` and replace all occurrences of `T` by `Action`. In the `Consume` method you then need to replace the code

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(task);
Thread.Sleep(1000);              // Simulate time-consuming task
```

by

```
task();
```

To enqueue a task you should do it exactly as it is done when using `PCQueue` by providing an `Action`. You can use a lambda expression for that.

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing up my confusion. I thought the Multithread-example might be something like a polymorphic solution, however it seem that I've been wrong;)

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this a lot by using `BlockingCollection`. This data structure is implemented as a queue that already encapsulates the producer-consumer logic.

```
public class PCQueue
{
  private Thread[] workers;
  private BlockingCollection<Action> queue = new BlockingCollection<Action>();
  private CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

  public PCQueue(int workerCount)
  {
    workers = new Thread[workerCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < workerCount; i++)
    {
      workers[i] = new Thread(Run);
      workers[i].Start();
    }
  }

  public void Shutdown(bool waitForWorkers)
  {
    cts.Cancel();
    if (waitForWorkers)
    {
      foreach (Thread thread in workers)
      {
        thread.Join();
      }
    }
  }

  public void EnqueueItem(Action action)
  {
    queue.Add(action);
  }

  private void Consumer()
  {
    while (true)
    {
      Action action = queue.Take(cts.Token);
      try
      {
        if (action != null) action();
      }
      catch (Exception caught)
      {
        // Notify somebody that something bad happened.
      }
    }
  }
}
```